# Regarding VB6 - Environment variable

Tags: vb6

Regarding VB6 :
I want to call 1 batch file using Environment variable, I am trying following code but i think some thing is missing that why its not working :

Code :

```
Dim sPathUser As String
sPathUser = Environ$("windir")
MsgBox sPathUser
Shell "sPathUser\test.bat"           ---> Here i m calling Batch file
```

So, can any one help me out please?

Comment: If this questions is about VB6 why did you tag it with vb.net and vba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Shell sPathUser & "\test.bat"`